# Replace characters in string without affecting names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to remove certain characters in a string ***without*** removing them from peoples names.

I have tried using nested `REPLACE` statements, adding multiple `CASE WHEN...THEN...ELSE` statements but I am struggling to cover all bases with the code

In my table I have peoples names with prefixes and suffixes used to denote the status of the person in a number of instances.

This is an example of data in the table

> ZZScott Buzzton SC

I need to remove the "ZZ" and "SC" text from here and just leave **Scott Buzzton**.

With the `CASE` statements I have been unable to get something that covers everything without layers of nesting

```
CASE
WHEN LEFT ( 'text' , 2 ) = 'ZZ' THEN STUFF ( 'text' , 1 , 2 , '' )
WHEN RIGHT ( 'text' , 2 ) = 'SC' THEN STUFF ( 'text' , LEN ( 'text' ) - 2 ) , 2 , '' )
ELSE 'text'
END
```

This only removes either "ZZ" or "SC" but not both.  I was wondering if there was something simple I could do to remove them that doesn't involve altering the data in the table as that could break a number of reports and possibly our application

ADDITION:  "ZZ" and "SC" are just 2 examples, there could be other texts used to denote status

Comment: Are they always going to a prefix and suffix? I *assume* you couldn't have someone with the "name" `'ScZZott BuzzSCton'`?

Comment: More or less, yes.  Most people won't have either so putting them in a CASE statement will only deal with people with only a prefix or only a suffix but not both

Comment: You say "more or less", so that means "no"? If there is (at least) one where that isn't true then the answer is "no". If they are all suffiixes/prefixes then it's just "yes". "more or less" doesn't actually give a helpful answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` is one method:

```
from t cross apply
     (values (case when t.col like 'ZZ%' then stuff(t.col, 1, 2, '') else col end)
     ) v1(col) cross apply
     (values (case when v1.col like ' SA%' then left(v1.col, len(v1.col) - 3) else v1.col end)
     ) v2(col)
```

Or, you could use brute force:

```
(case when t.col like 'ZZ% SA'
      then substring(col, 3, len(col) - 5)
      when t.col like '% SA'
      then left(col, len(col) - 3)
      when t.col like 'ZZ%'
      then stuff(col, 1, 2, '')
      else col
 end)
```

Comment: Hi Gordon.  Would this mean an APPLY for each piece of text I wanted to remove?

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the brute force CASE statement was the push I needed.  I'd spent so long looking into it I had completely ignored what was right under my nose!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to put that to some view/function using

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN RIGHT (col_1, 2) = 'SC' THEN STUFF(col_1, LEN(col_1) - 2), 2, '') ELSE col_1 END "col_1"
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN LEFT (col_1, 2) = 'ZZ' THEN STUFF(col_1, 1, 2, '') ELSE col_1 END "col_1"
    FROM myTable
)
```

(not tested)